# Question related to \left\{p\leq x| \ \text{the proprities $A_1(p), A_2(p),\ldots$ hold}\right\}.

Tags: number-theory, sieve-theory

It is not difficult to see that
$$\#\left\{p\leq x| \ \text{$p$ is prime and the proprities $A_1(p), A_2(p),\ldots, A_k(p)$ hold}\right\}<\frac{x}{\log x}.$$
Ma questions are:
$$1) \#\left\{p\leq x| \ \text{$p$ is prime and the proprities $A_1(p), A_2(p),\ldots, A_k(p)$ hold}\right\}\sim O(\frac{x}{\log^k x})?$$
2) Can we use sieve theory to prove that? Thank you

Comment: What is the property A_k(p)?

Comment: For example $A_k(p)$ are prime numbers. We can take $A_1(p)=p+4$ and $A_2(p)=p^2+4$, etc.

Comment: In this context the main conjecture is the random model for the primes : that $X_n = 1_{n \text{ is prime}}$ looks like a sequence of independent random variables with $P(X_n=1) = \frac{1}{\log n}$, where "looks like" means up to "trivial obstructions". There is no trivial obstruction for $n,n+2$ both being primes thus the model predicts $E[\sum_{n \le N} X_n X_{n+2}] =\sum_{n \le N} E[X_n]E[ X_{n+2}]]=\sum_{n \le N} \frac{1}{\log n}\frac{1}{\log n+2} \sim \frac{N}{\log^2 N}$